# Why mexHttpBinding is required in WCF service

Tags: web-services, wcf, wcf-binding

`mexHttpBinding` is required to exchange metadata over Http, this is useful when clients want to create proxy classes.

I have a WCF service without `mexHttpBinding` but i can still see its WSDL on the browser, i can still create proxy classes by adding reference of it in VS.

What is the exact need of this binding or am i missing something?

Comment: Please add your WCF configuration, it is hard to tell what is going on without seeing it

Answer (score 1):

My bad, below is the answer.

[MexHttpBinding v/s WSDL](https://abhishekdv.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/mexhttpbinding-vs-wsdl/)

Comment: Although this is helpful, it isn't answering the why.  Does WCFTestClient.exe work without mex binding the same as the browser page?  Or is mexHttpBinding truly just a fallback that is not needed?